# How can I make this table in MySQL fill in data automatically from another table?

Tags: mysql, datatables

So I have these two tables created and I need to make it to where the carmake is automatically entered into the in the currentcar field in the mechanics table, given the car id is also entered there? The carid is the primary key in the Cars tavle

Cars table

| carid | VIN | Make | YEAR | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Mechanics table

| mechanicid | firstname | lastname | title | carid | currentcar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
carid INT (100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
VIN INT (999999999999999999) NOT NULL,
Make VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
Year Year(4) NOT NULL,
Color VARCHAR(10)
);
Create Table mechanic(
mechanicid INT (100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
carid INT (100) NULL,
currentcar VARCHAR(100) NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(carid) REFERENCES cars(carid)
)
```

Comment: Don't do that. The whole point of a foreign key is that you can get the related information from the other table when you need it.

Comment: But if you really need this, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to set `NEW.currentcar`.

Comment: So should I just get rid of the foreign key aspect? I thought I would have to need it since I need it to get the other information from the cars table

Comment: Keep the foreign key, get rid of the `currentvar` column.

Comment: When you need the current make, join with the `cars` table.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks, I don't know why I did not think of the join concept

Comment: Also, why is `currentcar` `VARCHAR(50)` when `car.Make` is `VARCHAR(100)`?

Comment: That was a typo and I fixed it